# Azure KeyVault Config Builder connection string resulting in timeout

Tags: c#, .net, azure, entity-framework, azure-keyvault

Currently trying to populate our web.config connection string in our .net app with config builders and it's resulting in timeouts. I followed this [guide](https://dotnetthoughts.net/azure-key-vault-in-aspnet-mvc/). I can confirm the password to the db is correct. I have also already tried making sure to log in via the Azure CLI. This does not help. I would also note we are using a vpn into the db.

the error

```
SqlException: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=356; handshake=14649; 

System.Data.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'
```

Web.config file:

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
    <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="{vaultname}" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" /></builders>
  </configBuilders>
  <connectionStrings  configBuilders="AzureKeyVault">
  
      <add name="Entities" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://52.157.144.83:389/DC=INFORMATIONSECURITYTOOLKIT,DC=Local" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Is there a better way I could diagnose what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. The difference was when I was editing the connection string to be used with the @Microsoft.KeyVault secret reference in the app service deployment vs. just using the azure key vault config builder it my local web.config. In the former, I included tcp:......, 1433 in the datasource/server name and then id=id@server (i.e. sa@server.windows.net) for the id. In my local web.config I removed those changes and boom, it worked.